# Removing spaces from a variable in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, spaces

I am writing a file to remove spaces from filenames in a folder and then put the result in a `.txt` file.  I just get a result of "Echo is on." over and over.

This  is what I have so far:

```
@echo ON
SET LOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%# in (*.*) do (
    SET var=%%~n#
    Set MyVar=%var%
    set MyVar=%MyVar: =%
    echo %MyVar%>>text.txt
)
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Did you call the batch file echo.bat/cmd ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `ECHO is on.` is because delayed expansion was not used, which caused the value of `%var%` and `%MyVar%` to be inserted before the `for` command is run, and since they were not defined at the start, empty variables were inserted in. When the `echo %MyVar%>>text.txt` was run, it was interpreted as `echo >>text.txt`. When echo is run without any arguments, it outputs whether echo is on or off, which is what you get in `text.txt`.

To fix the problem, you have to do two things:

First, there is something wrong with your second line. There is no space between set and local in `setlocal`. The second line should be `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`.

Second, to use delayed expansion, you have to replace all `%`s in each variable with `!`, like `!var!` instead of `%var%`.

End result:

```
@echo ON
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%# in (*.*) do (
    SET var=%%~n#
    Set MyVar=!var!
    set MyVar=!MyVar: =!
    echo !MyVar!>>text.txt
)
```

You actually do not need to use a temporary variable in this case, you can just do         `SET MyVar=%%~n#` and skip to `set MyVar=!MyVar: =!`.

Answer (score 82):

Removing all spaces (not just leading and trailing) can be done without using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`with the following line:

```
set var=%var: =%
```

This works by replacing all spaces in the string with the empty string.

Source: [DOS - String Manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)

Comment: Worked perfectly when I wanted to remove the space between a letter and a variable (e.g., "_p 011820181033" needed to be "_p011820181033"). Thanks!

Comment: This trick is valid to replace other characters as well: just put the desired character to remove instead of space. For example, `set var=%var:.=%` will remove all the dots in the variable, which may be useful if you have a variable containing a version number with dots and you need just the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The wrong thing is you've enabled the variable expansion (you wroted it bad...) and also you are not using it, when you use enabledelayedexpansion you need to write the variable names as this: !Variable! instead of this else: %Variable%

But you don't need to use it with this code:

```
@echo ON
For %%# in (*) do (
    SET "var=%%~n#"
    Call Set "MyVar=%%var: =%%"
    Call echo %%MyVar%%>>text.txt
)
```

Comment: @foxidrive, It works, sorry but... you've tested it before comment?.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following batch in the folder holding the files to be renamed

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%j in (*.*) do (
    set filename=%%~nj
    set filename=!filename=.=_!
    set filename=!filename= =_!
    if not "!filename!"=="%%~nj" ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj"
    )
```

you just need to add the print to txt

Comment: that just removed all the file names and left the extensions

Answer (score 0):

The `set var=%var: =%` did not work for me.
So I tried with success for a number the following code:
`set /a var-=1 & set /a var+=1`

Comment: surely doesn't work for an alphanumeric string (which file names usually are). To remove (leading and/or trailing) spaces from a supposed *number*, just `set /a var=var` should do.