# White space in CMD output messing up commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I have a script that grabs a list of users and then sets a password for all of them, simple enough right? However, When I get the list of users using the wmic output (which is converted to the corrected format using a loop) each user gets an output similar to

```
    "Administrator      "
    "Guest         "
    "DefaultAdmin       "
    ...
```

now this list needs to be used in a loop to set the passwords which is a simple for loop to set the passwords, however when you use these users in command prompt it sees them as

```
    net user "Administrator      " Password
```

in which case there is not such thing as administrator with 6 spaces

My question is how am I to remove the spaces after the names without manually going in to the text document?

```
    (for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%X in ('wmic UserAccount where "LocalAccount=True" get Name') do (
        for /f "delims=" %%Y in ("%%X") do (echo %%Y)
    ))>AllUsers.txt
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001999/how-to-remove-trailing-and-leading-whitespace-for-user-provided-input-in-a-batch .

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276336/removing-spaces-from-a-variable-in-batch .

Comment: And another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310711/remove-trailing-spaces-from-a-file-using-windows-batch .

Comment: If you're running a `For` loop against the `WMIC` output, does that not mean you're setting each users' password to the same string? Could you please expand your script example appending your `WMIC` command; thank you.

Comment: Before asking how to remove the trailing spaces, I would try to avoid them to be generated... Share the code you are creating the list of strings with...

Comment: @aschipfl, unfortunately many WMIC values, this being one, are output as fixed width strings padded with spaces as necessary.

Comment: @Compo, not necessarily, when you add the `/VALUE` option...

Comment: I'm aware there are options available, @aschipfl, hence the reason I asked to see their WMIC command.

Comment: Confused on why you are not showing the code you used to get the list of users.

Comment: Its supposed to be a same password and theyre going to be set to enter a new password upon logging in @Compo

Comment: @Squahman I will add the code in an edit right quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send your `WMIC` output via a `Call` command, it will remove any leading or trailing spaces for you!

```
@Echo Off
For /F Tokens^=2^Delims^=^" %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_UserProfile Where^
 "Special!='True'" Assoc /AssocClass:Win32_UserAccount 2^>Nul'
) Do For /F "Skip=1Delims=" %%B In ('WMIC UserAccount Where^
 "SID='%%A' And LocalAccount='TRUE'" Get Name') Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%C In (
    "%%B") Do Call :Sub %%C
Pause
Exit/B

:Sub
Echo=Net User "%*" Password
GoTo :EOF
```

*Remove `Echo=` from the penultimate line to actually invoke the `Net User` command*

**Edit**

…and a quick example based upon the method mentioned in [aschipfl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579289/white-space-in-cmd-output-messing-up-commands?noredirect=1#comment82120061_47579289):

```
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%A In ('WMIC UserAccount Where^
 "LocalAccount='TRUE'" Get Name /Value') Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%C In (
    "%%B") Do Echo=Net User "%%C" Password
Pause
```

Comment: this works about right, only problem is that it also finds domain users. I don't need to find them for the reason i needed it

Comment: the one made by @aschiphls 's comment appears to work as intended with a very slight modification to make sure i wasnt accidentally grabbing a list of thousands of domain users on my network

Comment: @IdioticProphet, I have updated both examples to exclude outputting names of non local users.